Skewed (but deterministic) load distribution on OpenShift 4
We are migrating from OpenShift 3 to 4. Our application has an NGINX proxy in the DMZ namespace and the app is running in another namespace, exposed as services with ClusterIP. The NGINX simply refers to the upstream using the service object (Cluster IP).
On OpenShift 3 traffic is distributed evenly among pods. Unfortunately, in OpenShift 4, we see a skewed load distribution across pods in the requests entering the app namespace:

If the number of pods is a power of 2, then the distribution is even.
If it is not a power of 2, then a certain number of pods will receive exactly twice the amount of traffic as the others.

For example:

With 14 pods then 2 pods will receive double the traffic of the remaining 12.
With 18 pods then 14 will receive twice the traffic of the other 4 etc.

In fact it follows exactly a specific mathematical pattern (see end of the post) suggestive of being related to hashing. Unfortunately, it appears to be a hash function resulting in a highly skewed distribution. We would prefer a random distribution or round-robin to ensure it is even.
We could work around the issue by always using a number of pods that is a power of 2, but it is not ideal since it would limit flexibility and also raise questions what happens if a pod goes down unexpectedly or while scaling traffic.
We would appreciate any help in diagnosing the issue. Given the issue is new for us in OpenShift 4 we suspect it could be related to Redhat OVN which seems to employ hash-based strategies. As mentioned, we would like to eliminate hashing altogether to just have it be randomly distributed.
*) Mathematical pattern: If N is the number of pods then:

let X be the smallest power of two that is still >= N.
The number of pods receiving double traffic is then X mod N.

We have tried this up to 80 pods and the pattern holds. This seems consistent with a hashing pattern where one would take "mod" number of pods.
